# Could not load framework “ITunesSoftwareService.framework”, warning: Application validation was skipped

Tags: ios, xcode4.3, application-loader

I am getting this warning as soon as I updated my Xcode to 4.3.1

Could not load framework at “file://localhost/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Application%20Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/” (err = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The bundle “ITunesSoftwareService.framework” couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located." UserInfo=0x400124200 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle’s executable couldn’t be located., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSBundlePath=/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “ITunesSoftwareService.framework” couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located.})
warning: Application validation was skipped.

I looked up other questions and tried their answers, but of no avail. Following is the stuff i tried:

- Reinstall Xcode(reinstalled atleast 5 times :( )
- Update iTunes
- recreated all distribution certificates
- Set Skip Install to both 'yes' and 'no'

the app seems to work fine on my iPhone and the simulator tho.

BTW, in my Developer directory i don't see an Application directory as mentioned here:

```
/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework
```

I only see "Xcode" and "Shared" directories. 
Can someone tell me how to reinstall the required bundle?

Thanx.
Plz help me, I've been going crazy ever since i updated to Xcode 4.3.1 :(

Answer (score 1):

I found this 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html

I'm had the same issue, after I uninstalled the previous Developer folder as per instructions in the Xcode 4.3 manual. Upon re-install of Xcode and under the /Developer/Applications/Utilities/ I can see the Application Loader.app but once I click on it, it says "**You can't open the application Application Loader.app because it my be damaged or incomplete**." HOW ?